# Check if email already exists in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

I have a quiz form that is connected to my database, however I need to prevent duplicate email entries being inserted. 
I have tried the following:

```
//Check for duplicate email addresses
            function checkEmail($email){
                $sql = DB::select('email')->from('myquiz')->where('email','=','$email')->execute(); 

                $result = mysql_result(mysql_query($sql),0) ;

                if( $result > 0 ){
                die( "There is already a user with that email!" ) ;
                }//end if
            }
```

But I 'm still getting duplicate entries, here is all my code (may be I'm not running this in the correct place?)

```
 public function action_myquiz() {
    $this->template->styles['assets/css/myquiz.css'] = 'screen';
    $this->template->jscripts[] = 'assets/scripts/myquiz.js';
    $this->template->content = View::factory('quiz/myquiz');
        $this->template->content->thanks = false;
        if ($this->request->post('entry')) {
            $post = $this->request->post('entry');

            //Check for duplicate email addresses
            function checkEmail($email){
                $sql = DB::select('email')->from('myquiz')->where('email','=','$email')->execute(); 

                $result = mysql_result(mysql_query($sql),0) ;

                if( $result > 0 ){
                die( "There is already a user with that email!" ) ;
                }//end if
            }

            // save participant's info
            $stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO `myquiz` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `confirm_email`)
                                                                        VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :email, :confirm_email)');                                                     
            $stmt->param(':first_name', $post['first_name']);
            $stmt->param(':last_name', $post['last_name']);
            $stmt->param(':email', $post['email']);
            $stmt->param(':confirm_email', $post['confirm_email']);
            try {
                $stmt->execute();
            //  var_dump($post);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                FB::error($e);
            }

            $this->template->content->thanks = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rather than checking if email exists prior to insertion I would advise attempt to add in a try/catch block. Catch duplicate key exception and then indicate that the email is duplicate.

Comment: or make the email-field UNIQUE and then try catch like Raj said

Comment: also make sure you wrap vars in double quotes `'$email'` should be `"'$email'"` or just `$email`. You cannot parse vars inside single quotes

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to go with Raj's option as i think it would be the best :)

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You're never calling your `checkEmail()` function so it's never running. You should either remove that code from the function or just call the function where it needs to run.
2. In that function you're checking that no email exists that literally equals "$email". PHP will only parse variables in double quotes - change that line to use `where('email','=',"$email")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change mysql_result to mysql_num_rows as below first function and try.

```
$result = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql),0) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is never executed. You will need to define the function outside the action_myquiz function and then call it. Also in the 'where' clause your not passing the email address in correctly and you can just use 'mysql_num_rows' to return the number of rows.

Try this:

```
//Check for duplicate email addresses
private function checkEmail($email) 
{
    $sql = DB::select('email')->from('myquiz')->where('email', '=', $email)->execute(); 

    $result = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql),0) ;

   if( $result > 0 )
   {
       die( "There is already a user with that email!" ) ;
   }
}

public function action_myquiz() 
{
   $this->template->styles['assets/css/myquiz.css'] = 'screen';
   $this->template->jscripts[] = 'assets/scripts/myquiz.js';
   $this->template->content = View::factory('quiz/myquiz');
    $this->template->content->thanks = false;
    if ($this->request->post('entry')) {
        $post = $this->request->post('entry');

        // Check if email exists
        $this->checkEmail($_POST['email']);

        // save participant's info
        $stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO `myquiz` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `confirm_email`)
                                                                    VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :email, :confirm_email)');                                                     
        $stmt->param(':first_name', $post['first_name']);
        $stmt->param(':last_name', $post['last_name']);
        $stmt->param(':email', $post['email']);
        $stmt->param(':confirm_email', $post['confirm_email']);
        try {
            $stmt->execute();
        //  var_dump($post);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            FB::error($e);
        }

        $this->template->content->thanks = true;
    }
}
```

A couple of additional points:

- Raj is correct that a Try/Catch block might be better
- Ensure your data is escaped before passing into SQL queries, your framework might be doing this for you.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can't place a function inside another function.  So you need to place it outside your `action_myquiz` function.  You'll also want to change `mysql_result` to `mysql_num_rows`.  Something like this

```
//Check for duplicate email addresses
function checkEmail($email){
    $sql = DB::select('email')->from('myquiz')->where('email','=',"$email")->execute(); 
    $result = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql),0) ;

    if( $result > 0 ){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

//Now start your other function
function checkEmail($email){
```

Then inside your `action_myquiz` function you need to call your `checkEmail` function.  Like

```
if(checkEmail($email) === false) {
    //Proceed with insert
} else {
    //Don't do insert
}
```